# Read Firebase content Data android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to connect firebase and get all data under driver section
[have node and under this node have 3 items and want to get all data under this item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiTn3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Hock").child("Driver");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String point = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", point);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
driverRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
point1
point2
point3
```

Hope it helps.